# CvNormalBayesClassifier train error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCv to make a `CvNormalBayesClassifier`, but when I try to train it I get an error.
this is my code:

```
CvMat train=cvMat(1, 32, CV_32FC1, val);
CvMat res=cvMat(1, 1, CV_32FC1, type);
M1.train(&train, &res);
```

where `val` is an array of double and `type` is an array of just one int element. `M1` is my `CvNormalBayesClassifier`

the error I get is this one:

`OpenCV Error: Bad argument (There is only a single class) in cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/ml/ml_inner_functions.cpp, line 731
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/ml/ml_inner_functions.cpp:731: error: (-5) There is only a single class in function cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses`

Aborted

thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the last argument `cvMat` function has a `void*` type so it does not know the real type of your arrays. As result no data conversion is possible. But you are using `CV_32FC1` constant which assumes `float` type and `train` and `res` matrices just reinterpret bits of your int and doubles as floats. And your `CvNormalBayesClassifier` sees just a trash instead of real data.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that your response array, res, is completely uniform (which it would have to be as it has only element).  Either add a distinct value to allow the trainer to train, or tell it you're doing one-class training:

```
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type = CvSVM::ONE_CLASS;
M1.train(train, res, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

I've not worked with "ONE_CLASS", so you may need to give the "nu" parameter a value first (see this [OpenCV SVM doc page](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html?highlight=svm#cvsvmparams-cvsvmparams)).  Also, I don't think the amperesands are necessary.

Comment: Isn't `CvSVMParams` (and one-class classification) only relevant to an SVM classifier, not a Normal Bayes classifier?